# Multiply a Biginteger value by a double value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, double, biginteger

i want to multiply a Biginteger by a double like this

```
buyableObjects[index - 1].cost = buyableObjects[index - 1].cost * BigInteger.Pow((BigInteger)multiplier, buyableObjects[index - 1].indexMultiplier);
```

the problem is that multiplier is a double value equal to 1.15 and BigInteger ignores 0.15. Is there maybe a way to multiply the cost of my object which is a Biginteger value as well by a double value 1.15 and round it up to a biginteger?

Comment: Alternatively, use [`BigRational`](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/util/Koopakiller.Numerics/BigRational.cs#L1413) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.pow?view=netframework-4.8) that BigInteger.Pow() takes a BigInteger followed by a regular Base 32 integer. So If you're just going to use a double, I don't see why you're using the BigInteger.Pow() function.

Since we know that multiplier is a double and buyableObjects[index-1].indexMultiplier is an integer, 
I would instead do

```
double finalMultiplier = Math.Pow(multiplier, buyableObjects[index-1].indexMultiplier);
```

Then you just have to face the problem of multiplying your BigInteger by a double which you can solve by breaking it up into multiplication and division.

Say for example finalMultiplier = 2.27; You may have to do some rounding at this point since we aren't sure how many decimal places finalMultiplier will have. You can acheive this with the Math.Round() function.
For example:

```
    int decimalPlaces = 2;
    double finalMultiplier = 2.225f;
    finalMultiplier = Math.Round(finalMultiplier,decimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
    //Will round 2.225 to 2.22
    BigInteger cost = new BigInteger(500);
    cost *= ((BigInteger) (finalMultiplier * Math.Pow(10, decimalPlaces))); //Multiply by 222
    cost /= (BigInteger) (Math.Pow(10,decimalPlaces)); //Divide by 100
    print(cost); //1110
```

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding?view=netframework-4.8)'s some information on the different rounding Modes in C#. Doing it like this will help you specify how you want the rounding to happen and I've shown you how to implement some of the stuff other people have said about breaking up the decimal. I will leave you the liberty of substituting in the correct variables but hopefully this helps! All you have to do is replace cost with your BigInteger and use the finalMultiplier I provided up there. You can customize the decimalPlaces however you like.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead multiply by 115 and then divide by 100.